# how stop transfering form data when form is submitted to internal iframe?

Tags: php, file-upload

i have a upload file form and a iframe. form is submitted to a php script with target to iframe. i want to stop uploading file when user click on a stop uploading button.
how can i stop transfering data to iframe?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, MoosaMaher!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i use this:

```
function stopiframe('iframename'){
    if(/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent))
    window.frames['iframename'].window.document.execCommand('Stop');
    else
    window.frames['iframename'].window.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to break the connection. And the only way to do this is to reload the page with

```
btn.onclick = function() { window.location.reload(true); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You could reload the iframe though.